# Is it possible to file down the side of an expansion slot to fit a bigger card

Tags: expansion, expansion-cards

I want to use a PCIe x8 SSD on a motherboard with only an x1 slot open. Can I just file down the side of the card or the slot to fit it in?

Comment: I think PCIe allows you to plug an 8x card into a 1x slot without filing. Have you looked? If not, then don't.

Comment: No, don’t file down the PCB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://superuser.com/questions/921674/can-i-mechanically-modify-pcie-connectors-to-accept-wider-cards